# typolink with empty value

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I try to create a typolink with no Text in it. The result should be:

```
<a href="/index.php?id=123">‌</a>
```

I have 2 work arounds so far:

**adding a non-printing character:**

```
lib.mylink = TEXT
lib.mylink .value = &zwnj;
lib.mylink .typolink.parameter.field = field_link
```

Result:

```
<a href="/index.php?id=123">‌&zwnj;</a>
```

**adding a comment:**

```
lib.mylink = TEXT
lib.mylink .value = <!-- empty -->
lib.mylink .typolink.parameter.field = field_link
```

Result:

```
<a href="/index.php?id=123">‌<!-- empty --></a>
```

Is it possible to get `<a href="/index.php?id=123">‌</a>` without a work around?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just wrap raw URL with a tag manually:

```
lib.mylink = TEXT
lib.mylink.wrap = <a href="|"></a>
lib.mylink.typolink.parameter.field = field_link
lib.mylink.typolink.returnLast = url
```

Comment: Thanks. That works (in this case). But what if I have other infos in the typolink, like dynamic title-attribute then this will not work. What would be the way then? There is no way to set an emptystring?

Comment: You can use stdWrap.dataWrap instead of wrap and use field values in there: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#stdwrap-datawrap

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that was working for me:

```
lib.mylink = TEXT
lib.mylink.value (

)
lib.mylink .typolink.parameter.field = field_link
```

Important: Keep the empty line after "value (". This will render a simple line break in HTML. The visual result is the same as for an empty a-tag.